# datetime variable returning 'String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.'

Tags: datetime, bindingsource

I have an accdb database file with ExpiryDate set to DATETIME.
The datagridview is formatted to dd/MM/yyyy.
I am trying to filter the bindingsouce between to dates as follows:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DateTime srchDateTo = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(1);
        DateTime srchDateFrom = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-11);
        client1BindingSource.Filter = "ExpiryDate < #" + srchDateTo + "# And ExpiryDate > #" + srchDateFrom + "#";
    }
```

when i click the button i get: 'String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.'

I have put a messagebox in and the variables are in the correct format.

This is my first database and I have a lot to learn so I may not understand the replies until I have research the replies.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you need to format your DateTime before you paste it into your filter.

Try `.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")` at the end of your DateTime variables.

For example:

```
client1BindingSource.Filter = "ExpiryDate < #" +
    DateTime.Today.AddMonths(1).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "# And ExpiryDate > #" + 
    DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-11).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "#";
```

Happy coding :)

Comment: I still had the same error, but it gave me the idea to try the following:

Comment: string srchDateTo = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(1).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
            string srchDateFrom = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-11).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
            DateTime dateTo = DateTime.Parse(srchDateTo);
            DateTime dateFrom = DateTime.Parse(srchDateFrom);client1BindingSource.Filter = "ExpiryDate Is Not Null And " +
                "ExpiryDate < #" + dateTo + "# And ExpiryDate > #" + dateFrom + "#";

Comment: @Garry are you sure that the DateTime has to have this format? In Microsoft Docs they describe two formats with different settings for the location (US and non US). See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/format-a-date-and-time-field-47fbbdc1-52fa-416a-b8d5-ba24d881b698

Comment: I know stored data (DATETIME) and data display are pretty much unrelated.

Comment: (Sorry, i keep pressing enter for new line). my problem is the table field is DATETIME and the variable is DATETIME but I keep getting 'String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.' - I know NULL value is not a valid DATETIME format and I have none.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the string that is not a valid datetime was the field heading.
The answer is to use a string variable and not a datetime variable.

```
        string srchDateTo = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(1).ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy");
        string srchDateFrom = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-11).ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy");
        client1BindingSource.Filter = "ExpiryDate < #" + srchDateTo + "# And ExpiryDate > #" + srchDateFrom + "#";
```